# Get sales by coupon code

Tags: magento-1, coupon-codes

Is it possible to find sales by a particular coupon code?

OR

Is it possible to read orders on which a particular coupon code is applied?

I wrote a script earlier to filter orders on which discounts were applied?

```
$from_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_REQUEST['from_date']));
$to_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_REQUEST['to_date']));

$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from'=>$from_date, 'to'=>$to_date))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', array('eq' => Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE));

$orders->addFieldToFilter('base_discount_amount', array('lt' => 0));
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can definitely do this, see the following code:

```
$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
->addFieldToFilter('coupon_code','your_coupon_code');
```

Where 'your_coupon_code' represents the value of your coupon code.

Answer (score 0):

You can check particular order have coupon code or not using below code

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId('100000033');  
// 100000033 your order increment id
if($order->hasCouponCode()){
    echo $order->getCouponCode();
}
```

You can filter order by particular coupon code as Digital Pianism answer